# Why does my system shut down when playing a game?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

I have ATI Radeon 5870HD Graphics card and Asus Rampage III extreme MB. 
My computer completely shuts down while playing games. Also, Catalyst Control Center doesn't launch only. I have re-installed drivers several times but that didn't help. My OS is Win7 64 bit.

Here is my CPU-Z log:

```
CPUID HWMonitor Report
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Binaries
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

HWMonitor version   1.1.9.0

Monitoring
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Mainboard Model     Rampage III Extreme (0x000006B2 - 0xF3837805)

LPCIO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

LPCIO Vendor        Winbond
LPCIO Model     W83667HG
LPCIO Vendor ID     0x5CA3
LPCIO Chip ID       0xA5
LPCIO Revision ID   0x13
Config Mode I/O address 0x2E
Config Mode LDN     0xB
Config Mode registers   
        00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 
    00  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 0B FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    10  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    20  A5 13 FF 00 44 00 00 FF 40 00 00 7F 22 00 00 40 
    30  01 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    40  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    50  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    60  02 90 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    70  00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
Register space      LPC, base address = 0x0290


Hardware Monitors
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Hardware monitor    Winbond W83667HG
    Voltage 0   1.22 Volts [0x98] (VIN0)
    Voltage 1   12.27 Volts [0xDC] (+12V)
    Voltage 2   3.28 Volts [0xCD] (AVCC)
    Voltage 3   3.26 Volts [0xCC] (+3.3V)
    Voltage 4   5.18 Volts [0xD8] (+5V)
    Voltage 6   1.23 Volts [0x9A] (VIN6)
    Temperature 0   31°C (87°F) [0x1F] (SYSTIN)
    Temperature 1   41°C (105°F) [0x52] (CPUTIN)
    Temperature 2   26°C (77°F) [0x33] (AUXTIN)
    Fan 1       1430 RPM [0x3B] (CPUFANIN0)
Hardware registers  
Register space      LPC, base address = 0x0290
bank 0  
        00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 
    00  04 D7 04 C1 30 00 1E 20 01 9B 01 01 3C 3C 04 04 
    10  04 FF 30 00 00 01 01 3C 43 07 00 00 35 FF FF D0 
    20  98 DC CD CC D8 FC 9A 1F FF 3B FF DA 00 8E 53 F6 
    30  E2 40 0A C0 56 A0 40 40 43 61 C0 0A A9 80 CB FF 
    40  03 6E 00 FF FF 00 3F 35 2D 21 20 C0 10 95 00 A3 
    50  FF FF 00 FF FF FF 00 80 C1 6F FF FF 19 E0 00 05 
    60  04 C1 50 00 01 01 3C FF 0A FF 01 FF FF FF FF 14 
    70  32 32 32 32 32 33 FF FF FF FF FF 4B 22 00 1F FF 
    80  04 D7 04 C1 30 00 1E 20 01 9B 01 01 3C 3C 04 04 
    90  04 FF 30 00 00 01 01 3C 43 07 00 00 35 FF FF D0 
    A0  98 DC CD CC D8 FC 9A 1F FF 3B FF DA 00 8E 53 F6 
    B0  E2 40 0A C0 56 A0 40 40 43 61 C0 0A A9 80 CB FF 
    C0  03 00 00 FF FF 00 3F 35 2D 21 20 C0 10 95 00 A3 
    D0  FF FF 00 FF FF FF 00 80 C1 6F FF FF 19 E0 00 05 
    E0  04 C1 50 00 01 01 3C FF 0A FF 01 FF FF FF FF 14 
    F0  32 32 32 32 32 33 FF FF FF FF FF 4B 22 00 1F FF 
bank 1  
    50  29 00 00 4B 00 50 00 FA FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
bank 2  
    50  19 80 00 4B 00 50 1A 04 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
bank 3  
    50  02 01 07 02 00 01 07 01 04 00 00 D0 7E 01 00 00 
bank 4  
    50  39 13 FF 00 00 00 00 08 69 4E 1D B9 09 5D 20 7F 

Hardware monitor    Asus IROG 02
    Temperature 0   50°C (122°F) [0x32] (SB)
    Temperature 1   53°C (127°F) [0x35] (NB)
    Temperature 2   26°C (78°F) [0x1A] (OPT3)
    Temperature 3   26°C (78°F) [0x1A] (OPT2)
    Temperature 4   27°C (80°F) [0x1B] (OPT1)
    Fan 0       1599 RPM [0x63F] (Fan #1)
Register space      SMBus, base address = 0x0400
SMBus request       channel 0x0, address 0x40

        00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 
    00  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    10  FF 64 64 5A 5A 5A 5A FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    20  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    30  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    40  00 00 00 97 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    50  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    60  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    70  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    80  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 86 32 14 00 66 EC 
    90  3F 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    A0  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    B0  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    C0  27 32 35 1F 1A 1A 1B FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 30 00 
    D0  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    E0  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    F0  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 

Hardware monitor    Asus IROG 01
    Voltage 0   1.18 Volts [0x4A0] (CPU)
    Voltage 1   1.51 Volts [0x5E4] (DRAM)
    Voltage 2   1.11 Volts [0x457] (ICH Core)
    Voltage 3   1.51 Volts [0x5E4] (ICH PCIE +1.5V)
    Voltage 5   1.81 Volts [0x714] (CPU PLL)
    Voltage 6   1.16 Volts [0x48C] (IOH Core)
    Voltage 7   1.20 Volts [0x4B4] (QPI)
    Fan 0       1309 RPM [0x51D] (CPU OPT)
    Fan 1       1441 RPM [0x5A1] (CPU)
    Fan 2       671 RPM [0x29F] (Chassis #2)
    Fan 3       1026 RPM [0x402] (Chassis #1)
Register space      SMBus, base address = 0x0400
SMBus request       channel 0x0, address 0x43

        00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 
    00  FF 72 72 58 89 72 54 7F FF FF FF 00 00 FF FF FF 
    10  FF FF 00 00 08 FF 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 00 
    20  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    30  00 FF FF FF 85 00 43 01 00 2E 00 FF FF 01 00 FF 
    40  FF FF FF FF FF 00 FF FF 00 FF FF FF A4 FF FF FF 
    50  00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 FF 00 FF FF 
    60  FF FF FF FF 00 00 FF FF 01 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    70  01 FF FF FF FF FF 00 01 FF 00 09 FF FF 64 FF FF 
    80  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 99 1B 60 00 12 60 
    90  93 04 E4 05 57 04 E4 05 16 01 14 07 8C 04 B4 04 
    A0  1D 05 A1 05 9F 02 02 04 FF FF FF FF 45 00 FF FF 
    B0  FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    C0  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    D0  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    E0  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    F0  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 

Hardware monitor    AMD ADL
    Voltage 0   0.95 Volts [0x3B6] (VIN0)
    Temperature 0   40°C (103°F) [0x27] (TMPIN0)

Hardware monitor    Volterra VT1165
    Voltage 0   1.44 Volts [0x1B] (VID)
    Current 0   0.00 Amps [0x0] (CIN0)
    Temperature 0   36°C (96°F) [0x24] (TMPIN0)
Register space      class = 0x4, base address = 0x0FBCC0000
I2C request     bus 0x6, device 0x70

        00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 
    00  30 80 F0 60 66 5E 00 A7 84 00 24 00 00 D8 04 10 
    10  0F 06 02 44 01 38 28 31 39 01 0A 00 DB 55 00 1A 
    20  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    30  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    40  30 80 F0 60 66 5E 00 A7 84 00 25 00 00 D8 04 10 
    50  0F 06 02 44 01 38 28 31 39 01 0A 00 DB 55 00 00 
    60  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    70  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    80  30 80 F0 60 66 5E 00 A7 84 00 25 00 00 D8 04 10 
    90  0F 06 02 44 01 38 28 31 39 01 0A 00 DB 55 00 00 
    A0  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    B0  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    C0  30 80 F0 60 66 5E 00 A7 84 00 25 00 00 D8 04 10 
    D0  0F 06 02 44 01 38 28 31 39 01 0A 00 DB 55 00 00 
    E0  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    F0  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 


Processors
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Number of processors        1
Number of threads       8

APICs
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Processor 0 
    -- Core 0   
        -- Thread 0 0
        -- Thread 1 1
    -- Core 1   
        -- Thread 0 2
        -- Thread 1 3
    -- Core 2   
        -- Thread 0 4
        -- Thread 1 5
    -- Core 3   
        -- Thread 0 6
        -- Thread 1 7

Processors Information
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Processor 1         ID = 0
    Number of cores     4 (max 8)
    Number of threads   8 (max 16)
    Name            Intel Core i7 930
    Codename        Bloomfield
    Specification       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         930  @ 2.80GHz
    Package (platform ID)   Socket 1366 LGA (0x1)
    CPUID           6.A.5
    Extended CPUID      6.1A
    Core Stepping       D0
    Technology      45 nm
    TDP Limit       130 Watts
    Core Speed      2936.9 MHz
    Multiplier x FSB    22.0 x 133.5 MHz
    Rated Bus speed     2402.9 MHz
    Stock frequency     2800 MHz
    Instructions sets   MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, EM64T, VT-x
    L1 Data cache       4 x 32 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L1 Instruction cache    4 x 32 KBytes, 4-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L2 cache        4 x 256 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L3 cache        8 MBytes, 16-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    FID/VID Control     yes


    Turbo Mode      supported, enabled
    Max turbo frequency 3066 MHz
    Max non-turbo ratio 21x
    Max turbo ratio     23x
    Max efficiency ratio    12x
    TDC Limit       110 Amps
    Core TDP        110 Watts
    Uncore TDP      20 Watts
    Power @ 12x     40 Watts
    Power @ 13x     46 Watts
    Power @ 14x     52 Watts
    Power @ 15x     60 Watts
    Power @ 16x     68 Watts
    Power @ 17x     78 Watts
    Power @ 18x     89 Watts
    Power @ 19x     101 Watts
    Power @ 20x     115 Watts
    Power @ 21x     130 Watts
    Max bus number      255
    Attached device     PCI device at bus 255, device 2, function 0
    Attached device     PCI device at bus 255, device 3, function 4


Thread dumps
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

CPU Thread 0    
    APIC ID         0
    Topology        Processor ID 0, Core ID 0, Thread ID 0
    Type            01020001h
    Max CPUID level     0000000Bh
    Max CPUID ext. level    80000008h
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, D, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, I, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 2, U, 256 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 3, U, 8 MB, 16 thread(s)

    CPUID        
    0x00000000      0x0000000B  0x756E6547  0x6C65746E  0x49656E69
    0x00000001      0x000106A5  0x00100800  0x0098E3BD  0xBFEBFBFF
    0x00000002      0x55035A01  0x00F0B2E4  0x00000000  0x09CA212C
    0x00000003      0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
    0x00000004      0x1C004121  0x01C0003F  0x0000003F  0x00000000
    0x00000004      0x1C004122  0x00C0003F  0x0000007F  0x00000000
    0x00000004      0x1C004143  0x01C0003F  0x000001FF  0x00000000
    0x00000004      0x1C03C163  0x03C0003F  0x00001FFF  0x00000002
    0x00000005      0x00000040  0x00000040  0x00000003  0x00001120
    0x00000006      0x00000003  0x00000002  0x00000001  0x00000000
    0x00000007      0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
    0x00000008      0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
    0x00000009      0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
    0x0000000A      0x07300403  0x00000044  0x00000000  0x00000603
    0x0000000B      0x00000001  0x00000002  0x00000100  0x00000000
    0x0000000B      0x00000004  0x00000008  0x00000201  0x00000000
    0x80000000      0x80000008  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
    0x80000001      0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000001  0x28100800
    0x80000002      0x65746E49  0x2952286C  0x726F4320  0x4D542865
    0x80000003      0x37692029  0x55504320  0x20202020  0x20202020
    0x80000004      0x30333920  0x20402020  0x30382E32  0x007A4847
    0x80000005      0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
    0x80000006      0x00000000  0x00000000  0x01006040  0x00000000
    0x80000007      0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000100
    0x80000008      0x00003024  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000

    MSR 0x0000001B      0x00000000  0xFEE00900
    MSR 0x0000003A      0x00000000  0x00000005
    MSR 0x000001A0      0x00000000  0x00850089
    MSR 0x000000CE      0x00000C00  0x00011501
    MSR 0x00000017      0x00040000  0x00000000
    MSR 0x00000035      0x00000000  0x00040008
    MSR 0x000000C1      0x00000000  0x00000000
    MSR 0x000000C2      0x00000000  0x00000000
    MSR 0x000000C3      0x00000000  0x00000000
    MSR 0x000000C4      0x00000000  0x00000000
    MSR 0x00000186      0x00000000  0x00000000
    MSR 0x00000187      0x00000000  0x00000000
    MSR 0x000001AD      0x00000000  0x16161617
    MSR 0x0000019A      0x00000000  0x00000000
    MSR 0x000001A4      0x00000000  0x00000000
    MSR 0x000001AC      0x00000000  0x03700410
    MSR 0x000001FC      0x00000000  0x00000003
    MSR 0x00000300      0x00000000  0xE0000001
    MSR 0x0000019C      0x00000000  0x88320000
    MSR 0x000001A2      0x00000000  0x00641400
    MSR 0xC0000103      0x00000000  0x00000000
    MSR 0x00000198      0x00000000  0x00000016
    MSR 0x00000199      0x00000000  0x00000016


Storage
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

USB Device          Generic USB Hub, class=0x09, subclass=0x00, vendor=0x0424, product=0x2512
USB Device          USB Composite Device, class=0xEF, subclass=0x02, vendor=0x05A9, product=0x2649
USB Device          Generic USB Hub, class=0x09, subclass=0x00, vendor=0x0424, product=0x2514
USB Device          DeathAdder Mouse, class=0x00, subclass=0x00, vendor=0x1532, product=0x0016
USB Device          Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Detection Driver (USB), class=0x00, subclass=0x00, vendor=0x045E, product=0x0745

Graphic APIs
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

API             ATI I/O
API             ADL SDK

Display Adapters
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Display adapter 0   
    Name            Radeon HD 5870
    Codename        RV870
    Technology      40 nm
    Memory type     GDDR5
    GPU ref clock       27000
    PCI device      bus 4 (0x4), device 0 (0x0), function 0 (0x0)
    Vendor ID       0x1002 (0x1043)
    Model ID        0x6898 (0x032E)
```

Comment: Tastes like burning...

Answer (score 4):

What is the output rating of your power supply?

- 140W for CPU
- 100W for videocard
- 20W for disk
- +30% for ventilation

… and a 200W PSU is cooking already with 300W warming up.

Comment: In addition to [Zab's answer](http://superuser.com/a/415168/24500) , I'd also check under Event Viewer.  Bugcheck messages, especially ones where the computer crashes over moving one bit in memory are a dead giveaway of hardware problems.

Comment: HI,@Zeb I'm using 1000W Power supply. Hi, @slchk I did check the bug repoet it says The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x0000001e (0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000). A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 042412-42245-01. hope it helps. Thank you guys for taking your time to help me. pls pardon my bad posting as i'm new to this and still learning.

Comment: 1e with blank addresses id 99% overclocked RAM showing errors.

reset your BIOS to DEFAULTS and try again.